# Cant get Weighted Cosine Similarity to work

Tags: perl, module

I'm trying to get the Weighted Cosine Similarity of two documents. I'm using [Text::Document](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Document) and [Text::DocumentCollection](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::DocumentCollection). My code seems to work but it isn't returning a number as I expected.

Here is my code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Document;
use Text::DocumentCollection;

my $newfile  = shift @ARGV;
my $newfile2 = shift @ARGV;

##This is in another file.
my $t1 = countFreq($newfile);
my $t2 = countFreq($newfile2);

my $collection = Text::DocumentCollection->new(file => 'coll.db');
$collection->Add("One", $t1);
$collection->Add("Two", $t2);

my $wSim = $t1->WeightedCosineSimilarity( $t2,
    \&Text::DocumentCollection::IDF,
    $collection
);

print "\nWeighted Cosine Sim is: $wSim\n";
```

All this returns is `Weighted Cosine Sim is:` without anything following the colon.

Here is the code for countFreq:

```
sub countFreq{
my ($file) = @_;

my $t1 = Text::Document->new();

open (my $info, $file) or die "Could not open  file.";
    while (my $line = <$info>) {
        chomp $line;
        $line =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
    foreach my $str (split /\s+/, $line) {
        if (!defined $sp{lc($str)}) {
            $t1 -> AddContent ($str);
    }
}
}
    return $t1;
}
```

Comment: The issue is probably in `countFreq`. `$1` and `$t2` must return a valid `Text::Document` object for `$collection ->Add` to work. It isn't exported by either of the modules. Where does it come from?

Comment: countFreq creates a new Text::Document file and reads through the file assigning it to $t1. It returns $t1. I use this so the file type works with the collection and WeightedCosineSimilarity method.

Comment: Please always `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program

Comment: Thank you. Please show the code for `countFreq`

Comment: You clearly didn't `use warnings 'all'` unless you did so in addition to `use warnings`

Comment: Also, are there two documents on line somewhere that I can use to test with please?

Comment: I've been testing it with text documents including just a few sentences. You could test it with any two different text documents.

Comment: Do you also get `Use of uninitialized value $wSim in concatenation`? And what should I do for `coll.db`?

Comment: No I don't get that. 'coll.db' is part of what I don't understand. There's no 'coll.db' in my computer.

Comment: The only way you will ever be able to test your code reliably is to obtain two text files whose *weighted cosine similarity* is known. I have succeeded in getting zero instead of `undef` from the method, but I cannot achieve a useful value no matter how similar or different, long or short I make the sample texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###Update

Here's an example program that works fine. It's based on looking at the test code in the distribution for inspiration

I was expecting the test to be much less sensitive, so I was getting zeroes from two wildly different text sources. This example adds three short sentences `$d1`, `$d1`, and `$d3`, to a collection `$c`, and then compares each of the three documents to `$d1`

Comparing `$d1` to itself produces 1 -- an exact match, as expected, while comparing `$d2`and `$d3` gives 0.087 and 0 respectively -- a partial match and no match at all

I hope this helps you to resolve your specific issue?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Text::Document;
use Text::DocumentCollection;

my $d1 = Text::Document->new;
$d1->AddContent( 'my heart belongs to sally webster' );

my $d2 = Text::Document->new;
$d2->AddContent( 'my heart belongs to the girl next door' );

my $d3 = Text::Document->new;
$d3->AddContent( 'I want nothing to do with my neighbours' );

my $c = Text::DocumentCollection->new( file => 'coll2.db' );

$c->Add('one',   $d1);
$c->Add('two',   $d2);
$c->Add('three', $d3);

for my $doc ( $d1, $d2, $d3 ) {

    my $wcs = $d1->WeightedCosineSimilarity(
        $doc,
        \&Text::DocumentCollection::IDF,
        $c
    );

    die qq{Invalid parameters for "WeightedCosineSimilarity"} unless defined $wcs;

    print $wcs, "\n";
}
```

###output

```
1
0.0874311036726221
0
```

---

This is the code for `Text::Document::WeightedCosineSimilarity`

```perl
# this is rather rough
sub WeightedCosineSimilarity
{
    my $self = shift;
    my ($e,$weightFunction,$rock) = @_;

    my ($Dv,$Ev) = ($self->{terms}, $e->{terms});

# compute union
    my %union =  %{$self->{terms}};
    my @keyse = keys %{$e->{terms}};
    @union{@keyse} = @keyse;
    my @allkeys = keys %union;

# weighted D
    my @Dw = map(( defined( $Dv->{$_} )?
        &{$weightFunction}( $rock, $_ )*$Dv->{$_} : 0.0 ),
        @allkeys
    );

# weighted E
    my @Ew = map(( defined( $Ev->{$_} )?
        &{$weightFunction}( $rock, $_ )*$Ev->{$_} : 0.0 ),
        @allkeys
    );

# dot product of D and E
    my $dotProduct = 0.0;
    map( $dotProduct += $Dw[$_] * $Ew[$_] , 0..$#Dw );

# norm of D
    my $nD = 0.0;
    map( $nD += $Dw[$_] * $Dw[$_] , 0..$#Dw );
    $nD = sqrt( $nD );

# norm of E
    my $nE = 0.0;
    map( $nE += $Ew[$_] * $Ew[$_] , 0..$#Ew );
    $nE = sqrt( $nE );

# dot product scaled by norm
    if( ($nD==0) || ($nE==0) ){
        return undef;
    } else {
        return $dotProduct / $nD / $nE;
    }
}
```

I'm afraid I don't understand the theory behind what it is doing, but it looks like your problem is that either `$nD` ("norm of D") or `$nE` ("norm of D") is zero

All I can suggest is that your two text samples may be too similar/different, or perhaps they are too long/short?

Either way, your code should look like this so as to catch an invalid return value from the cosine function:

```perl
my $wSim = $t1->WeightedCosineSimilarity( $t2,
    \&Text::DocumentCollection::IDF,
    $collection
);

die qq{Invalid parameters for "WeightedCosineSimilarity"} unless defined $wSim;

print "\nWeighted Cosine Sim is: $wSim\n";
```